# Price data from yahoo finance (or google finance) that is more precise than one point per day

Tags: python, pandas, finance, yahoo-finance, google-finance-api

Is it possible to retrieve historical price data from yahoo (or google) finance using pandas.io.data.yahoo in python with hour or 10 minutes resolution instead of 1 point per day? If it is not possible, is it limitation of pandas module or yahoo (google) finance API?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about pandas.io.data.yahoo , but you may need this:

Jsons of Bloomberg:

http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/AAPL:US

http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1M/AAPL:US

Comment: How does this answer the question by posting links to data? The OP is asking whether the Pandas API for reading yahoo finance data supports a different resolution of data and whether the issue is with Pandas or Yahoo.

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to retrieve such data not only for last day, but for arbitrary day?

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, the deepest level you can get using their free API is 1-point a day.

It's a limitation of yahoo not of pandas.
If you browse the code of [pandas.io.data](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/data.py), you'll see that they get the data setting the parameters in the URL http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv? for yahoo and http://www.google.com/finance/historical? for google.

If you go directly to yahoo.finance, you also can get only 1 point a day data: [example of General Electrics historical prices](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GE%20Historical%20Prices)
You can also access the API of yahoo running an SQL query against their API via [yql console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/):

```
select * from yahoo.finance.stocks where symbol="ge"
```

If you go there to a tree view and then to results, you'll see again that 1 point a day is the highest resolution for historical prices.

You can however get the real time prices since there are [some options](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm) in yahoo's API.  If you write the script that queries yahoo API about the price each 10 minites, after a while you'll get a price history in higher resolution. As an example an URL that gets the real price for Google and Apple:

```
finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG&f=nb2t1
```

AAPL and GOOG are tickers for Google and Apple respectively. b2 is a real time ask price, n is the name of the corporation and t1 is the time of the last trade.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ystockquote package in python. It pulls data in a clean format from the yahoo finance rest api.

See implementation examples here. 
https://github.com/cgoldberg/ystockquote

Comment: This actually doesn't answer either question.